# Post to an application's page with the page using application token? koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Every day I want to run a rake task that will post an update to the application's Facebook page. The page is defined under Facebook > App > Settings > Advanced (at the bottom).

I want to get the an app access token and then post as the page to the page. This is kind of what I was thinking, but it doesn't work:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(CONFIG['appid'], CONFIG['appsecret'])
@token = @oauth.get_app_access_token
@page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@token)
@page_graph.put_connections('NAME_OF_PAGE','feed', :message => 'This is posted as the page')
```

The error I get:

```
OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

I don't know if there is a place for (I tried passing as an option in @oauth.get_app_access_token):

@oauth.get_app_access_token(:permissions => "manage_pages")

Still nothing. Any ideas?

---

[UPDATE]

So I changed to:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(CONFIG['appid'], CONFIG['appsecret'])
@token = @oauth.get_app_access_token
@page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@token)
@postid = @page_graph.put_connections(CONFIG['appid'],'feed', :message => 'This is posted as the page')
```

Then when I output @postid, I get a valid ID. I put this id into: https://graph.facebook.com/POSTID and I get a valid response.

This is super confusing. Why is it not appearing on the page??

Comment: @page_graph.put_connections(CONFIG['appid'],'feed', :message => 'This is posted as the page')

gives no error, but it's still not posting to the feed

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. So far, I only found this method for OAuth, in order to get permission to publish:

@oauth.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => "publish_stream")

but I keep having the error that I can't apply this method to a string. I presume it fails and it doesn't return a oAuth structure, but a string instead.